# Flask routes using blueprint are not working, only '/' route is working on Ubuntu, But all is fine on Windows

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, routes, blueprint

I have created routes like the following in the graph.py file

```
bp = Blueprint('graph', __name__, url_prefix='/')

from flask import jsonify
@bp.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def index():
    return render_template("graph/index.html")

@bp.route("/patent", methods=(['GET', 'POST']))
def patent():
    return render_template("graph/patent.html")

@bp.route("/literature", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def literature():
    return render_template("graph/literature.html")
```

it is working fine on my localhost(windows) but on the server(Ubuntu 18) it runs the simple route ('/') but with the name ('/patent', 'literature') it is not working.
The Error on web browser is following

**Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.**

Comment: It seems no problem with code. Do all html files are in the right directory?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you get correct page with `/` ? Maybe you have other route with `/` in other file and you get different page - and it would measn all your route in this file doesn't work.  Where is main code with `app = Flask(...)` ? How do you add `Blueprint` to this `app` ? Did you run it with `debug=True` ? Did you run it using built-in server in Flask or with other web server like `nginx`, `apache`, `gunicorn`, etc.

Comment: maybe see doc [Blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/) - there is `app.url_map` to see routes after `app.register_blueprint(bp)`

Comment: Windows is case insensitive whereas linux is. Have you checked that you don't use uppercase chars in your directories ? This would lead to windows running your script correctly, but linux failing to run it since `Graph` and `graph` are different to linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed 3rd parameter (url_prefix='/'), and then all routes is working well for Ubuntu.

```
bp = Blueprint('graph', __name__)
```

please visit website http://18.212.192.49